# Spring Boot application does not write logs into logging file on Wildfly 14

Tags: spring-boot, logging, wildfly

I have deployed my Spring Boot appication WAR file onto Wildfly 14.0.1. In this application I need to write logs in specific file. I use configuration defined in logback.xml

logback.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>
                %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE-AUDIT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>myProject_audit.log</file>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>
                %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss};%msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </encoder>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- rollover daily -->
            <fileNamePattern>myProject_audit.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>


    <logger name="audit-log" level="info" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDIT"/>
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </logger>

    <root level="error">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Inside bussiness class there's following:

```
public class Service1Controller {
    private static  Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger("audit-log");

    public ResponseEntity getList(){

        LOGGER.info("Inside Service1 getList");

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("Spain");
        list.add("China");
        list.add("France");
        list.add("USA");

        LOGGER.info("Printing service1 list " + list);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(list);

    }

}
```

my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>kz.djadiv</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo-jboss-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
    </parent>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

After deployment to Wildfly the file myProject_audit.log (as I defined it in logback.xml) is being created. But there's nothing inside. None line of logs.

I tried to add src/main/resources/META-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml with following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" />
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
            <module name="org.jboss.logging" />
            <module name="org.jboss.logging.jul-to-slf4j-stub" />
            <module name="org.jboss.logmanager" />
            <module name="org.jboss.logmanager.log4j" />
            <module name="org.slf4j" />
            <module name="org.slf4j.impl" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

But nothing changed

Comment: Any ideas, please?